# How do I give generics a constraint to reference types?

Tags: c#, generics

I have this situation:

```
public class FOO<T> where T : IBar
{
    private T _xxx;
    public Y(T xxx)
    {
        if (xxx == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("xxx");
        _xxx = xxx;
    }
}

public interface IBar 
{
    string XString { get; }
}
```

In the constructor, I am checking `T` for `null`. The compiler correctly warns me that I am checking for `null` on something that may be a value type, as `IBar` could be implemented by a struct.

How can I constraint `T` to be a reference type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *typical myth* (even I got before) is types which derive from interface are implicitly  reference types, but it's actually not. *Struct* also could have interface.

So, you should add more constraints `class` to indicate as reference type

```
public class FOO<T> where T : class, IBar
```

Comment: Strictly speaking that's wrong, class specifier must be before any other. //edit. Now it's +1 with clear conciseness.

Comment: @Cuong Le: Thank you for the enlighenment. I have often used the 'class' constraint, but only because the compiler told me to :-)